# How Retrieve Data according to User role in PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm retrieving data into table using PHP with MySql. In my program there are few users Admin,user2,user2.
My table name 'employee' and contain this columns employee_id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_position, employee_city, employee_extension, employee_joining_date, employee_age. I retrieved these all data into table using this https://coderexample.com/datatable-search-by-datepicker/ example code.Now I want to retrieve data by user. I mean if logged in as user1 table should show the data related with employee_city=San Francisco. If logged in as user2, table should show the data related with employee_city=London. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have another table to define those relationships. User_Employee table; if you are using laravel eloquent its easy. But with normal php files after you have the relation table you can hard code roles or create a page to assign those roles to your user or assign them upon registration.

share your codes its easier to help